# Understanding "unbiased ridge regression"

Tags: unbiased-estimator, ridge-regression

Could someone please explain what "$J$" consists of in this [paper](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.utgjiu.ro%2Fmath%2Fsma%2Fv04%2Fp08.pdf&ei=RhX0UNLcCMim4ASy-IDgBQ&usg=AFQjCNE8atO375vGfPifjzcpbDdyBwa4_Q&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.Yms), equation 1.5.
$$
J \sim N(\beta, \sigma^2 I/k)
$$
What's $\beta$ here? What's $N$?

Also, why are they putting that much effort in deriving $k$ with complicated formulas instead of just saying "use CV to find the best $k$"?

Comment: I cannot see any $N$ above!  Yes, this seems to be somewhat mystical.  To find out what is the idea behind $J$ above I think you must look in the references of the paper you have given. $\beta$ seems to be the true value of the regression parameter, so $J$ seems to be a random variable. Seems to be some sort of randomized estimator? If you are interested in this you must go to the references in your cited paper.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer part of your question, at least.  $J$ is a random variable with a normal distribution (that's what $N$ means---normal).  $\beta$ is the mean of $J$; $σ^2I/k$ is the standard deviation.

Since $\beta$ is the slope in the original linear regression $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ (equation 1.1), it's probably appearing in equation 1.5 as a stand-in for $\beta$.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @caedocyon. This looks like a nice contribution--I hope we'll see more. Let me note a couple of (admittedly small) points: I suspect $\sigma^2I/k$ is a diagonal matrix of *variances*, not SDs; also, since this is a multivariable situation, it might be clearer to state that $\beta$ is the mean *vector* / the vector of slopes from the original model. (NB, I haven't read the paper, these are guesses, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.)